# Как ограничить количество выбраных элементов по классу?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Пример кода тут, как сделать так чтоб я мог выбрать любые три элемент, а потом уже не мог выбрать?

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/47027/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.row').on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100px;
  height: 25px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: red;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.row {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 15px;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.row.active {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row"></div>
  <div class="row"></div>
  <div class="row"></div>
  <div class="row"></div>
  <div class="row"></div>
  <div class="row"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Одновременно не может быть более трёх `.row.active`? Делать проверку:

```
$('.row').on('click', function(){
    var activeRowsCount = $('.row.active').length
    if (activeRowsCount < 3 || $(this).hasClass("active")) { $(this).toggleClass('active'); }
});
```

Comment: Одновременно может быть 3, т.е. от 1 до 3 включительно.

Comment: спасибо большое!))

Comment: Именно так код в ответе и работает, проверьте.

Comment: @СтаниславКремса Пожалуйста :) Если ответ вам подошёл - отметьте его правильным, нажав на серую галочку.

Comment: @Klimenkomud Так выключить "active" пользователь сможет, когда их три?

Comment: А почему когда я выбрал три элемента, и хочу например один убрать, а выбрать другой то не могу? Но если выбрать один или два, и сделать тоже самое то убирается(

Comment: @Igor, сможет, если я правильно понял "хотелку" автора - именно так(а не заблокировать переключение вообще)

Comment: @Klimenkomud не, не сможет. Надо так: `if (activeRowsCount < 3 || $(this).hasClass("active"))`

Comment: @Igor Действительно, спасибо, поправил ответ

Comment: @СтаниславКремса Обновил ответ, попробуйте этот код.

Comment: Работает как я хотел, спасибо) Сейчас нажму галочку)